# A simple UITextView clips text with non-system font

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, typography

I’m displaying text in a `UITextView`, with a non-system font (i.e., I’ve bundled it with my application). A portion of that text (namely, taller-than-normal ascenders) is getting clipped in the `UITextView`.

Here is how I create my `UITextView`:

```
UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
tv.font = [UIFont fontWithName:MY_INSTALLED_FONT_NAME size:54.f];
tv.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];
tv.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
tv.text = @"Hello\nHello";
```

When I add my `UITextView` to the view hierarchy, I see:

[image: image of UITextView with clipped font]

A common suggestion for problems *like* this (though I did not find anyone with the very same issue) is to make sure `clipsToBounds` is `NO` and to try modifying the `contentInset` property of the `UITextView`. These don’t help. Another screenshot (showing `contentInset` adjustments):

[image: image of UITextView with clipped font and a non-zero contentInset]

Using various tools (e.g. [Reveal](http://revealapp.com) or the private method `recursiveDescription` on `UIView` both help), I have discovered that the text is clipped by a subview of the `UITextView` that seems to be meant to display the content. In iOS 6, that view is of type `UIWebDocumentView`.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It looks like something is wrong in you configuration file for the font. Maybe the vertical spacing if not set correctly?

Comment: @msgambel thanks for the suggestion. The other fonts I am using (from the same source) are displayed properly, however, and the folks providing the font are very experienced providing digital fonts. Additionally, rough inspection of `UIFont` properties (`ascender`, `capHeight`, etc.) look correct. However, it's good to check everything, and I'll be sure to take a look at the font itself.

Comment: did you get solution @TimCamber?

Answer (score -3):

There is a option in plist with name "Fonts provided by application".there you need to enter your CustomFont name..dont forget to add font file into your project...then it will work

Comment: I don't think it's an issue loading the font. The fonts themselves are displaying, just with this issue described above. (Maybe I'm misunderstanding you?)